# "UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment" After using global variables

Tags: python

I'm trying to access a variable inside a function that I've already tried making global, but that doesn't work. Here's my code (trimmed down with no unnecessary variable declarations):

```py
global col
col = 0
def interpret(text):
  for char in text:
      col += 1
```

The error I get says:

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 156, in <module>
    interpret(line) (Where I call the function in the rest of the code)
  File "main.py", line 21 (5), in interpret
    col += 1
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'col' referenced before assignment
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: `global col` should be inside `interpret`.

Comment: Every variable on the left side of an assignment (also augmented ones) in a function is seen as local if not explicitly declared global with "global".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have the `global` statement inside the function:

```py
col = 0

def interpret(text):
    global col
    for char in text:
        col += 1
```

Assigning `col` outside the function creates the variable, but to be able to write to it inside a function, the `global` statement needs to be inside each function.

btw As a programmer you should try very, *very*, **very** hard not to use globals.

You should pass variables into functions for them to operate on:

```py
col = 0

def interpret(text, cnt):
    for char in text:
        cnt += 1
    return cnt

text = ...
col = interpret(text, col)  # pass col in and assign it upon return.
```

Comment: Okay, I'll try this. You said I shouldn't use globals. Is there an alternative?

Comment: Yes, you should pass variables into functions for them to operate on. I will update my answer with an example.